# Stop wordpress from requesting external jquery from googleapi

Tags: plugins, jquery, google

Instead of using external jquery hosted on google i would like to use a local copy. I am able to tell wp to use the local version, however, I seem to be unable to stop wp requesting the google hosted one. when I do (in functions.php):

```
`function register_local_juery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'url/to/local/jquery', array(), null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_local_juery');`
```

The result of this is that wp includes both. The local and external. How can I stop wp from using the external source? In times of increasing awareness with privacy, shouldn't that be a kind of more obvious option? Is it possible that the call to googleapi is initiated by any plugin I have installed? Or do they always use the one registered with wp theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress *doesn't* use externally hosted jQuery. In fact, as far as I'm aware, WordPress core does not register *any* externally hosted scripts.

WordPress bundles its own version of jQuery, and you can enqueue the bundled version by just enqueueing the handle `jquery`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

Or by specifying `'jquery'` as a dependency:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', '/path/to/my-script.js', [ 'jquery' ] );
```

If you enqueue jQuery like that, but it's still loading an externally hosted version, then your theme or a plugin is either loading its own version separately, or has re-registered `jquery` with an external version. The easiest way to find the culprit is to deactivate plugins, checking your site after each one, to see if the correct version is loading.